# Consecutive bool indexing with assignment in numpy

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
>>>myarray = np.zeros(4)
>>>index_array1 = np.array([True, False, True, False])
>>>index_array2 = np.array([False, True])
```

I would like to assign values to `myarray` after consecutive bool indexing with `index_array1` and `index_array2`. Unfortuantely, the first bool indexing copies the array so that the second bool indexing works on a copy. `myarray` is unchanged.

```
>>>myarray[index_array1][index_array2] = 3
>>>myarray

array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

I have already a solution for this, but i find it a bit counterintuitive. Is there any better solution than

```
>>>myarray[np.where(index_array1)[0][index_array2]] = 4
>>>myarray

array([0., 0., 4., 0.])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be based on editing the initial mask with the *secondary-mask* -

```
In [9]: index_array1[index_array1] = index_array2

In [11]: myarray[index_array1] = 4

In [12]: myarray
Out[12]: array([0., 0., 4., 0.])
```